# Homotopy as a continuous path

Tags: homotopy-theory

Given two continuous maps $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$, the standard definition of a homotopy between f and g is that of a continuous map $H: X \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$ for every $x \in X$.
Is it equivalent to describe a homotopy as a path $t \mapsto h_t$  of continuous maps with $h_0=f$ and $h_1=g$ which is continuous in some topology on $C(X,Y)$?

Comment: Yes. The [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) is one such topology, I believe. Maybe some expert can say more about exactly which topologies give this result.

Comment: @RobArthan I see, thank you Rob!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thm.** *If $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, the map
$$
\Psi\colon C(X\times Z,Y)\to C(Z,C(X,Y))
$$
defined as $\Psi(H)(z)(x)=H(x,z)$, is a homeomorphism when the spaces of continuous functions are given the* compact-open *topology*.

*Proof:* [Lecture 12: Function spaces (part 4)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1shTZiP_pA&list=PLKnx70LRf21eSXaawNhiCCPrzsbLdT5do&index=24&t=83s).

Apply this result to the case $Z=[0,1]$ to get a homeomorphism
$$
\Psi\colon C(X\times[0,1],Y)\to C([0,1],C(X,Y))
$$

Note that the hypothesis on $X$ is automatically fulfilled for paths and loops: In the former case $X$ is an interval $I$ (usually $[0,1]$) and in the latter $\mathbb S^1$. In other words,
$$
C(I\times[0,1],X)\to C([0,1],C(I,X))$$
and
$$
C(\mathbb S^1\times[0,1],X)\to C([0,1],C(\mathbb S^1,X))
$$
are homeomorphisms for any topological space $X$.

A second theorem shows that when $K$ is compact and $X$ metric, the compact-open topology of $C(K,X)$ agrees with the topology induced by the distance between functions
$$
d(f,g)=\sup\{d(f(\zeta),g(\zeta))\mid\zeta\in K\}.
$$
Thus, given that $I$, $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb S^1$ are compact, when $X$ is a metric space, $\Psi$ can bee seen as a homeomorphism of metric spaces.

Comment: I was not aware of such result, it seems like a powerful and versatile theorem.
And it applies perfectly to answering my questions! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @noname. I've added a further note, in case you are interested.