# Continuity of a collection of functions (supertopology...?)

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I was pondering about the definition of topology and how it lets us define continuous function. Before I go into my question, I would like to share how I understand topology over a set. To speak about regularity/ continuity of a function, it would not be enough to talk about what happens pointwise in the domain and codomain but one would need to speak of what happens **near** points (the subsets we choose define which near points we consider).

So, I thought, suppose we have an indexed family of functions $\{f_{\alpha} \}$ where $f_{\alpha}: X \to Y$, then would it be a **useful pursuit** to consider the **continuity of the collection of functions as a whole**? So, the topology we use on the domain and codomain would be some subset of  $P(P(X))$ and $P(P(Y))$.

What are some interesting theorems which could be found as a result of defining continuity on a family of functions like this?

When I tried pondering about it, I think so maybe this may help in some theorems related to uniform convergence but I am not sure.

---

**Sidenote:** I think that this could be even done for collection of a collection of function by considering the powerset of the power set of the power set of the sets in domain and codomain.

Comment: Equicontinuity is a concept. See Arzela-Ascoli

Comment: [A homotopy between two paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) (see also [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4160436/homotopy-as-a-continuous-path)) and [continuous flows in topological dynamics](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22topological+dynamics%22+%22continuous+flow%22) might be of interest.

Comment: That is related but not the same. When  Ichecked the theorem you said, it requires a metric to define it seems @FShrike